# SQL count and group by not returning counts with 0

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

In my situation, I have an Employee table and a Department table. Most departments have employees, but there exist a few departments with zero employees.

I'm trying to pull up all departments, sorted with most employees to none.

I have tried both `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` and still can't seem to get what I want.

```
SELECT COUNT(Department.DEPT_ID) as total, Department.Name
FROM Department
  INNER JOIN Employee
    ON Department.DEPT_ID = Employee.DEPT_ID
GROUP BY Department.Name
ORDER BY total desc, Department.NAME asc;
```

However, this excludes any departments with zero employees. I also tried:

```
SELECT Department.NAME, IFNULL(COUNT(Department.DEPT_ID), 0) as total
FROM Department
  LEFT JOIN Employee
    ON Employee.DEPT_ID = Department.DEPT_ID
GROUP BY Department.NAME 
ORDER BY total desc, Department.NAME asc;
```

But this time, for any department with zero employees, it sets its value as 1, instead of 0 which is confusing me.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Correct solution by @vkp is:

```
SELECT Department.NAME, IFNULL(COUNT(Employee.DEPT_ID), 0) as total
FROM Department
  LEFT JOIN Employee
    ON Employee.DEPT_ID = Department.DEPT_ID
GROUP BY Department.NAME 
ORDER BY total desc, Department.NAME asc;
```

Comment: use `COUNT(Employee.DEPT_ID)` in the `left join` version.

Comment: @vkp (I'm sure you know, but just to clarify) also, use the left join version.

Comment: @user1935361 .. thought it was implicit. to be clear, i included your comment in the suggestion.

Comment: @vkp got it, makes sense.

Comment: Skip the IFNULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.deptname,CASE WHEN e.total IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE e.total END AS total
  FROM dept d
  LEFT JOIN 
       (
         SELECT deptid,COUNT(*) AS total
           FROM emp
         GROUP BY deptid
        ) e
    ON d.deptid = e.deptid
ORDER BY CASE WHEN e.total IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE e.total END DESC;
```

Comment: This is incorrect as it results in departments with zero employees to have a value of 1, instead of 0.

Comment: Pls upvote and accept the answer if u liked the solution. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Department.Name, 
CASE
    WHEN Employee.ID IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE COUNT(1)
END AS total
FROM Department
    LEFT JOIN Employee
    ON Department.DEPT_ID = Employee.DEPT_ID
GROUP BY Department.Name
ORDER BY total desc, Department.NAME asc;
```